# UIPageViewController VCs overlapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

I'm facing a strange problem whereas the `UIViewControllers` I present in a `UIPageViewController` have a width of **328** instead of **320** and appears to be flowing out of their bounds.

When viewing say page index 0, I can see a mm or two of page index 1 on the right hand side. **Why is this?** I'm using AutoLayout and create my `UIPageViewController` like so:

```
        self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:@{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey : [NSNumber numberWithFloat:pageSpacing]}];
        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
        self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
        [self.pageViewController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];
        [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


        /* remove dots */
        NSArray *subviews = self.pageViewController.view.subviews;
        UIPageControl *bottomControl = nil;
        for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
            if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]]) {
                bottomControl = (UIPageControl *)[subviews objectAtIndex:i];
            }
        }
        bottomControl.hidden = true;

        /* set viewcontrollers */
        self.navViewControllers = @[
                                    leftViewController,
                                    centerViewController,
                                    rightViewController
                                    ];

        [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[self.navViewControllers[1]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: What's `pageSpacing`?

Comment: @stefandouganhyde a `CGFloat`, tried with values ranging from 0-4 but they all produce strange results. I changed almost all of my controls recently to use AutoLayout instead of setting frames, which seems to be when the problem occured. Before than however, I had to set all the full-screen components in the pages to have a superview constraint constant of 0 rather than -20 which it apparently gets if you stretch it out, completely covering the scene

Comment: If you're seeing part of page index 1, wouldn't that suggest that page index 0 is less than 320 wide? The 8 point difference is suspicious because that is the default width of the margin. Check your leading and trailing constraints to see if any are constrained to their superview's margin instead of edge.

Comment: @MikeTaverne might be onto something there. I'll check my constraints when I get home today, about 10pm and check back then

Comment: @MikeTaverne sorry for the late response! Got a little too much to do the last days. Looking at it now. I set up 3 viewcontrollers to be used for the `UIPageViewController` - 2 of them are instantiated from storyboard using `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` but I haven't begun work on page index 0 yet, so it's simply a placeholder VC initialized like this: `[UIViewController new];`